# Ext4 partition 8TB

Tags: hard-drive, partition

Just setup a 8TB disk with gparted as GPT with a single ext4 partition, but now that is mounte it says:
/dev/sdc1              7,3T   38G    6,9T   1% /mnt/BACKUP

Why only 7.3T are available, the ext4 would use the other 700GB?
If I setup multiple partitions I can get more space for data?
i.e. 2 partition of 4 TB would change the situation?

Thanks, BR

Comment: Actual formatted capacity of a hard-drive is never the full amount listed on the box. An 8TB physical disk will always be less than the 8TB. If this is a virtual disk, it's tough to say how it was provisioned. Some are above the requested amount, where others are below. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Capacity

Comment: What happens if you use `tune2fs` to adjust the reserved space?  Read up on this first, but it would be `tune2fs -m0 /dev/sdc` to set reserved space to 0 percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because HDD vendors rarely (if ever) use KiB/MiB/GiB/TiB (x1024) as notation for their storage, but use KB/MB/GB/TB (x1000) instead. Your OS / filesystem uses binary-multiple prefixes, opposed to the industry standard of decimal-multiple prefixes.

```
Examples and comparisons with SI prefixes
one mebibyte    1 MiB = 220 Byte = 1,048,576 Byte
one megabyte    1 MB = 106 Byte = 1,000,000 Byte
one gibibyte    1 GiB = 230 Byte = 1,073,741,824 Byte
one gigabyte    1 GB = 109 Byte = 1,000,000,000 Byte
one tebibyte    1 TiB = 240 Byte = 1,099,511,627,776 Byte
one terabyte    1 TB = 1012 Byte = 1,000,000,000,000 Byte


8 TB = 8000000000000 B

Byte based with decimal-multiple prefixes (powers of 10): 
8000000000 KB (kilobyte) 
8000000 MB (megabyte) 
8000 GB (gigabyte) 

8 TB (terabyte) Byte based with binary-multiple prefixes (powers of 2): 
7812500000 KiB (kibibyte) 
7629394.53125 MiB (mebibyte) 
7450.58059692383 GiB (gibibyte) 
7.27595761418343 TiB (tebibyte)
```

Source: http://wintelguy.com/tb2tib.html

Ext4 adds overhead for sure, but it should be more like ~1,5% of the space.

Answer (score 0):

**Reserved Space**

By default, ext4 reserves 5% of the space for root.  You can adjust this using `tune2fs -m percentage device` so in your case, `tune2fs -m0 /dev/sdc`.

That should give your space back.